# Entity framework change in database

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-6

## What to do when changing database on Entity Framework

Hi,
I am using Microsoft Entity Framework with C#. I used a code first method so that entity framework created some magic code for me so that i didnt need to write it. Now, i need to change my database a bit. Need to add columns in the table and so on. How can i do this? Is there any other option that applying code first method again?? I found this solution a little bit cruel so i ask for help. Haven't found anything useful on google so i try here.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

When updating the database using the code first approach, you want to use Migrations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591621.aspx

It automatically scans your changes and creates a Migration object for each set of changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is some steps that you need to take, and I think it is better to refer you to the original documentation of it on MSDN:

You can find your solution here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621.aspx

look at the parts that talks about Enabling Migrations and Generating & Running Migrations.